# Manipulate nested object in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

From this array:

```
  objNeeded = [
    {onelevel: 'first'},
    {
      onelevel: 'second',
      sublevels: [
        {onelevel: 'domain'},
        {onelevel: 'subdomain'}
      ]
    },
    {
      onelevel: 'third',
      sublevels: [
        {
          onelevel: 'fourth',
          sublevels: [
            {onelevel: 'domain'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I need to obtain this object:

```
  objNeeded = {
    first: true,
    second: {
      domain: true,
      subdomain: true
    },
    third: {
      fourth: {
        domain: true
      }
    }
  };
```

It can be have more nested objects and more objects on the array.

How i can obtain this with JavaScript or Typescript?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: @Nicolas I have tried with map, but map return an array and i want an object.

Comment: You might want to add that in anyways. It might help us helps you.

Comment: [How to create a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion for that. Since this is a very specific problem to your usecase, i won't bother explain it here. I've left some comment in the code though.

```js
const objNeeded = [
    {onelevel: 'first'},
    {
      onelevel: 'second',
      sublevels: [
        {onelevel: 'domain'},
        {onelevel: 'subdomain'}
      ]
    },
    {
      onelevel: 'third',
      sublevels: [
        {
          onelevel: 'fourth',
          sublevels: [
            {onelevel: 'domain'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
  // from what i understand, the rule ares 
  // 1. if the value is a string, it becomes {[key]: true}
  // 2. if there is subLevels, we recursive build the subs arrays. 
 function recursivalySetSubLevels(elements) {
   // this is the output
   const output = {}
   // we parse every element of the array ( or sub array ) and assign them to the current oneLevels value.
   elements.forEach(element => {
    // if the element has subLevels,
    if(!!element.sublevels) {
      // we recursively build the sub object
      output[element.onelevel] = recursivalySetSubLevels(element.sublevels);
    } else {
      // otherwise, we set the key of the oneLevel to true;
      output[element.onelevel] = true;
    }
   });
   // and then return the object.
   return output;
 }
 
 console.log(recursivalySetSubLevels(objNeeded));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `Array#reduce` and recursive call

1. For `Array#reduce` use to recreate the array to object format
2. For recursive call used to find the inner sublevels

```js
const objNeeded = [{onelevel: 'first'}, { onelevel: 'second', sublevels: [ {onelevel: 'domain'}, {onelevel: 'subdomain'} ] }, { onelevel: 'third', sublevels: [ { onelevel: 'fourth', sublevels: [ {onelevel: 'domain'} ] } ] } ];

const res = objNeeded.reduce((acc, {
  onelevel,
  sublevels
}) => (acc[onelevel] = sublevels ? recCall(sublevels) : true, acc), {});

function recCall(arr) {
  return Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(({
    onelevel,
    sublevels
  }) => ({
    [onelevel]: sublevels ? recCall(sublevels) : true
  })))
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function `convertObject` which can get your desired result.

`for (obj of currentObj)` will loop through `array` values and convert the object.

`Object.keys(obj)` will return array of all the `key` in the object. and `.includes` will check whether `value` passed in parameter is exists in array or not.

Inside `convertObject` there is a recursion call is there which will be called when current array object has `sublevels`.

```js
function convertObject(currentObj) {
  // result object
  let result = {};

  // loop through array values
  for (obj of currentObj) {
    // check whethere obj has sublevels or not. If it has sublevels then call recursively.
    if (Object.keys(obj).includes("sublevels")) {
      // retrieve converted object for current object.
      result[obj.onelevel] = convertObject(obj.sublevels, result[obj.onelevel]);
    } else {
      result[obj.onelevel] = true;
    }
  }

  // return result.
  return result;
}

let objNeeded = [{onelevel: 'first'}, { onelevel: 'second', sublevels: [ {onelevel: 'domain'}, {onelevel: 'subdomain'} ] }, { onelevel: 'third', sublevels: [ { onelevel: 'fourth', sublevels: [ {onelevel: 'domain'} ] } ] } ];

console.log(convertObject(objNeeded));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```js
const objectNeeded = [...];

const reducer = (acc, level) => {
  if (level.onelevel) {
    acc[level.onelevel] = level.sublevels && level.sublevels.length
      ? level.sublevels.reduce(reducer, {})
      : true;
  }
  return acc;
};

// Obtain needed object
objectNeeded = objNeeded.reduce(reducer, {});
```